# How to get read of automatic checked radio button in a Boolean data type in Thymeleaf, Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im using spring-boot back-end with the fontend thyme-leaf . But the problem is when im putting Boolean data type in a radio button then the value which is set to 0 is automatically checked in the font end, event if i try to add th:checked="unchecked" its not working. My code is given bellow

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="isDownloadable"> Is Downloadable</label> <br>
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{isDownloadable}" value="1" th:checked="checked">Yes
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{isDownloadable}" value="0"> No<br>
    </div>
```

As here iv tried to cheack Yes radio button but its checked the No radio button in the front end.How to solve this problem ?

[here is the output of my code given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Rrb.jpg)

Comment: Why is the value 0 and 1?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli in the SRS its said so , there will be 0 or 1 value . thats why

Comment: What  do you mean with SRS? Have you read the docs: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#radio-button-fields

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  software requirements specification (SRS)

Comment: But why does anybody care about the values? You want to use Radio Buttons with Thymeleaf

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes i have read those document , but the problem is in those example the value was string , and not defined in the scope there . but in my problem the value is 0 and 1 and defined in that scope .

Comment: hmm dont know actually, but need the 0 and 1 somehow as the value

Comment: But you never use the values! You use a boolean isDownloadable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 0 and 1, you put need to condition and show data.Solution is

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="isDownloadable"> Is Downloadable</label> <br>
    <input type="radio" value="1" th:checked="${history.Shift == 1} ? ${true}">Yes
    <input type="radio" value="0" th:checked="${history.Shift == 0} ? ${true}"> No<br>
</div>
```